# migrated question is not updated with username

Tags: discussion, support

While roaming in meta stackoverflow I came across an user named [**@Krampus**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/21960/krampus).  I checked one of his best answer [Is the Stack Exchange engine available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16055/233367) 
where I found his username as **Al Everett**.  on clicking, it redirects to his profile named as *Krampus*.

Here is a couple of screenshots

[image]

[image]
I guess it happended because it is a *migrated question* whereas I don't see it in other questions.